How to replace column of one df with column of another df based on multiple matching columns?
I have 2 dataframes that look like this:
current_df
   id    email approved comment  order_id   country           region   date
0  3211  None   False    Others  abc_123    Greece            Europe   2024-04-02
1  3476  None   False    Others  xyz_456    Czech Republic    Europe   2024-04-02

previous_df
   id    email         approved  comment            order_id   country           region    date
0  3899  abc@test.com  True    Test Comment abc    abc_123    Greece            Europe   2024-03-03
1  3001  xyz@test.com  True    Test Comment xyz    xyz_456    Czech Republic     Europe   2024-03-03

In the above 2 dfs, I want to update the first df with email,approved,comments values from the second df based on matching (order_id,country,region) combinations in both df. (id and date will remain same as the first df.
For eg: the output will look something like this:
current_df
   id    email        approved    comment           order_id     country           region          date
0  3211  abc@test.com   True      Test Comment abc  abc_123      Greece            Europe   2024-04-02
1  3476  xyz@test.com   True      Test Comment xyz  xyz_456    Czech Republic     Europe    2024-04-02

P.S : Instead of updating the current_df, it is absolutely fine if a new df needs to be created, but the outcome should be the same.

have you tried a join?

Yes I tried that, and got extra set of columns from the second df, whereas I want to over-write the 3 columns of first df with that of the second df.

@say_n - Do you need current_df.drop(['email','approved','comment'], axis=1).merge(previous_df.drop(['id','date'], axis=1),  on=['order_id','country','region'], how='left') ?
